# Mapstruct source is List and target is direct attribute

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

I want to map UserDTO and UserGroupDTO where User has address as a list in which it has all address fields and Usergroup has individual address fields. Please let me know how could I map these fields.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no official support for that, but there is a workaround using *expressions*, as described in the ticket : https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1321#issuecomment-339807380

This would work your case:

```
@Mapper
public abstract class UserDTOMapper {

    @Mapping( expression = "java(userDTO.getAddress().get(0))", target = "street")
    @Mapping( expression = "java(userDTO.getAddress().get(1))", target = "zipCode")
    @Mapping( expression = "java(userDTO.getAddress().get(2))", target = "country")
    abstract public UserGroupDTO mapTo(UserDTO userDTO);

}
```

But you have to make sure that the address property implemented as List will always contain the same number of fields and in correct order, else the mapping based on list index will not work as expected.